# Default buttons of alert dialog are not working in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using AlertDialog to show some data using xml file. But when I inflate an xml in AlertDialog then default buttons are not displaying.
Please help

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Can we see your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add new buttons into your xml file and get id of that button and put click listener on this button.
This is working for me.

Comment: Your answer may be helpful to him. so just add a part of code as a answer.

Comment: why there is no code in this andwer

Comment: that one work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(Splash.this);
    final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.text_entry, null);

    //text_entry is an Layout XML file containing two text field to display in alert dialog

     final EditText input1 = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText input2 = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);             
                     input1.setHint("roomnumber");
                     input2.setHint("hotelname");
                     AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this);

                     alert.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details)
                          .setTitle("Enter the Text:")
                          .setView(textEntryView)
                          .setPositiveButton("Your Default button text", 
                              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                         Log.i("AlertDialog","TextEntry 1 Entered "+input1.getText().toString());
                                         Log.i("AlertDialog","TextEntry 2 Entered "+input2.getText().toString());
                                         if(isOnline())
                                        {       
                                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */

                                  }else{


                                  }
                                  }
                              });

                     alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem !
You need to set onclick listener to the all the buttons inside the dialog. Follow the code bellow.

```
  public void showDialogWithIcons() {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.icons_dialog);

            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));

            Button yesButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yesanswer_icons);
            yesButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    TextView tvForIconToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textInThePicture);
                    tvForIconToChange.setTypeface(tf);
                    tvForIconToChange.setText(getMyTextForIcon());
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }

            });
            dialog.show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because its ur custom layout.
To use buttons in custom dialog, define buttons in ur custom layout xml and then in the code do this :

```
Button xyz = (Button)dialog.findViewbyId(R.id.abc)
xyz.setOnClickListener(this or new View.OnClickListener)
```